# GPE using SpaCy identifies locations which are not geographical locations

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, spacy

I am using spacy library in my NLP code to identify the prominent geographical locations mentioned in the text.

But Spacy is identifying words which are not geographical locations along with the geographical locations such as: "BA297", "Legal", "Nutrigain", "Arham", "Stephen" and many more.

Is there any solution or better library?

Here is the code I am using to identify the geo locations:

```
# Load spaCy English model
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

# Perform named entity recognition (NER) using spaCy
entities = []
for word in df['words']:
    doc = nlp(word)
    for ent in doc.ents:
        entities.append((ent.text, ent.label_))

# Extract GPE entities
gpe_entities = [entity[0] for entity in entities if entity[1] == 'GPE']
```

Comment: If `df['words']` is a column that only contains single words then I'm not entirely surprised this doesn't work too well. Spacy is trained to annotate `documents` which should at least be sentences so the model has access to `context`.

Comment: It does not contain single word, it contains the full sentence

Comment: As far as I can tell you're doing it correctly then